# Cannot Read Property sendAsync of Undefined

Tags: node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am currently working in a NodeJS environment and am trying to run a contract function through web3js.

I am currently using version 0.2.3 i think for other dependencies reasons.

This is my code snippit:

```
async runfunction(abi, addr, functionToRun) {
    const MyContract = new this.web3.eth.contract(abi).at(addr);
    console.log('MyContract', MyContract)
    const txHash = await MyContract.FunctionName('param1','param2')//.sendAsync().get();
    // TRIED THIS : const txHash = await MyContract.FunctionName().sendAsync().get();
    // ALSO THIS const tx = await  MyContract.FunctionName('new string').call().then(function (id) { console.log(id) })
    console.log(txHash);
  }
```

When I run this however i get the following issue:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
> ‘sendAsync’ of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property ‘sendAsync’
> of undefined

When I console.log MyContract I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Web3.js 0.2.x is years old. I suggest you upgrade to latest and also update your code to match the current documentation. There is no really point to troubleshoot versions that are no longer maintained.

Comment: I will take this into consideration thank you.